# Wired connection takes a long time to connect on startup

Tags: networking, internet

The ethernet connection I'm running on Ubuntu takes random time to connect to the internet. It looks like it attempts it several times and after one of them it works. Setting a static IP didn't resolve the issue, it kept disconnecting and reconnecting.

The result of `ifconfig`:

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:ee:7b:74:74:c0  
      inet addr:192.168.1.8  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::beee:7bff:fe74:74c0/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6774 errors:105 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:8903327 (8.9 MB)  TX bytes:991472 (991.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:186427 (186.4 KB)  TX bytes:186427 (186.4 KB)
```

Answer (score 0):

TX packets:6774 ***errors:105***

You're getting errros on the interface. Try replacing a cable and using another port on the router/switch